# How to remove unwanted characters if their pattern known

Tags: python

It is known some strings start with a single letter (lower and uppercase), then unknown number of digits, and finally an underscore. Example:

```
myStringA = 'c17898_some other characters and symbols'
myStringB = 't72_ another example string 18925 t 12 S'

myStringC = 'does not have any numbers at all'
```

If a string starts with the pattern described I need to be able to remove it leaving only those characters that don't follow the pattern:

```
singleLetter + unknownNumberOfDigits + underscore.
```

How to achieve it simplest?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You want to use a [regular expression](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression) for this. The following code will remove the pattern you specified, only if it appears at the start of string `^`.

```
import re

pat = "^[A-Za-z][0-9]*_"
myStringA = 'c17898_some other characters and symbols'

output = re.sub(pat, "", myStringA)
print output
```

Comment: @Sputnix, You are welcome. Please mark this as the accepted answer if it resolved your question.